# Populate dictionary from MySQL python

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I am pulling data from a MySQL db which comes in as a list.

```
'''
    my_cursor.execute(sql_str)
    my_results = my_cursor.fetchall()
    print(my_results)
'''
```

OUTPUT
[('Allen, Jamie', 2), ('Anderson, Abbie', 1391), ('Anderson, Marcie', 1380), etc.,etc.

Instead of a list, I want to populate a dictionary.

```
'''
    my_cursor.execute(sql_str)
    my_result = {}
    my_result = [{'Name': row[0], 'ID': row[1]} for row in my_cursor.fetchall()]
    print(my_result)
'''
```

OUTPUT
[{'Name': 'Allen, Jamie', 'ID': 2}, {'Name': 'Anderson, Abbie', 'ID': 1391}, etc.

As you can see I am getting a list of directories not a directory. I really would appreciate your help.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the list to a dictionary like this:

```
L = [('Allen, Jamie', 2), ('Anderson, Abbie', 1391), ('Anderson, Marcie', 1380)]

D = dict(L)

print(D)
```

Now the dictionary D looks like this:

`{'Allen, Jamie': 2, 'Anderson, Abbie': 1391, 'Anderson, Marcie': 1380}`

Comment: after hours of trying, the function worked great. many thanks

Comment: Happy to help !, can you please mark my answer as correct (the green check image) ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a *list* comprehension, so you're getting a list:

```
[{'Name': row[0], 'ID': row[1]} for row in my_cursor.fetchall()]
```

if you want a dictionary, use a dictionary comprehension instead:

```
$ python3 ./t.py
{'Dan': 1, 'John': 2}
```

```py
data = [
  [ "Dan", 1 ],
  [ "John", 2 ]
]
print({row[0]: row[1] for row in data})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows:

```
my_cursor.execute(sql_str)
my_result = {}
for x, y in a:
    my_result[x] = y
print(my_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what library you're using for SQL, you may actually just be able to pass `dictionary = True` as an argument when creating your cursor object - I know this at least exists in [mysql-connector-python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html).

```
my_cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what MySQL package you're using. If it's [mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/), you can use `my_cursor.description` or `my_cursor.column_names`:

```
colnames = my_cursor.column_names
# Alternate for older library versions: colnames = [desc[0] for desc in my_cursor.description]
my_results = [dict(zip(colnames,record)) for record in my_results]
```